# Python GTK3: button with image and label and get the Label value after click event

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I'm trying to get the label value that is inside a Grid and that grid is inside a button after a click event.

This is my part of code:

```
for one_text in text_list:
    label_for_button = Gtk.Label(one_text)
    label_for_button.set_line_wrap(True)
    image_for_button = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("img.png")
    grid_in_button = Gtk.Grid()
    grid_in_button.add(image_button)
    grid_in_button.attach_next_to(label_for_button, image_for_button, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
    grid_in_button.show_all()
    button.add(grid_in_button)

    button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    # here i wanna get the value of the label_for_button
```

Help.. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: second argument of your function contains information about your button. in function `on_button_click` write `print(widget.get_label())`, see if it works

Comment: i've done it but it returns "None". 
maybe because it contains, the button, a grid and the label is inside the grid.

Comment: the solution for this is: `widget.get_child().get_child_at(0, 1).get_label()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this code helps:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk,GdkPixbuf

def btn_clicked(widget):
    print(widget.get_label())

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(filename="img.png", width=24, height=24, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
img = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
btn = Gtk.Button(label='some text',image=img,)
btn.connect('clicked',btn_clicked)
win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.add(btn)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but you need to add `btn.set_always_show_image(True)` so it can show the image.
For the code i made i've found a solution for it:
`widget.get_child().get_child_at(0, 1).get_label()`
**widget** is the button.
**.get_child()** to get the Grid.
**.get_child_at(0, 1)** to get the label at that position.
**.get_label()** to get the text from it.